# Matlab: Partitioning an image into blocks and putting a watermark into the LSB of each block

Tags: image, matlab, partitioning, watermark, block

I have an 256x256 image and I want to partition it into 16x16 blocks. Then I want to set the LSB of each block to zero. After that I want to use an MD5 function with a user key, an image ID, the image's width and height, the block's index and the image block X' (X' is the same with image block X with the exception of the LSB witch is set to zero) as parameters. Then I want to perform an XOR operation between the hash that has been produced by the MD5 function and the corresponding block of my watermark and insert the result of this to the LSB of my image block to get the watermarked image block. I'm trying to use the blockproc function, but I don't know what I shall use as a fun in this. I couldn't find anything on the net. Thank you for your help and sorry for my english!

Comment: Poor English (and the evidence suggests that your English is actually very good) is not a hindrance to good answers here on SO. Failure to show your code is such a hindrance.  The absence of code makes many SOers think that we're being asked to do your job for you rather than help you iron out the wrinkles.

Comment: Sorry if I gave the impression that I want someone else to do my job. Of course I don't want such a thing. But I can't start producing any code, because my problem is that I have to simultaneously get access to the image block and the corresponding watermark block to perform the necessary xor operation and start developing my code and I can't find a way to do so with blockproc. To summarize, my problem is how can I use blockproc to take the blocks by two images at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use imread at native mode. Then you can convert blocks to byte and bits. Then you can replace the desired bits.